# Build problem with monodevelop/mnotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I haven't tried to use monotouch in a while.  I've recently upgraded to snow leopard and to the most recent monodevelop and monotouch (from within monodevelop) and apple sdk (directly from apple).  Somewhere along the line I installed monomac.  Now when I try to build an iphone app I get this error:

Build Failed.Method not found. MonoDevelop.MacDev.MacBuildUtilities.UpdateCodeBehind

How can I clean things up so that it doesn't look for this method when building an iphone app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling MonoMac under AddInns seems to do it but is there a way to leave MonoMac enabled and yet have MonoDevelop know it shouldn't go look for MonoDevelop when building for iphone?